# Make FilterLogEventsRequest more efficient

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

The following code is taking 60 seconds or more to retrieve no more than a dozen short log events.

Any implicit inefficiencies in my code?

```
public List<String> getCWLogEvents(String logGroupName, String logStreamNamePrefix, Long startTime, Long endTime) {

    List<String> logMessages = new LinkedList<String>();

    try {
        FilterLogEventsRequest filterLogEventsRequest = FilterLogEventsRequest.builder()
                .logGroupName(logGroupName)
                .logStreamNamePrefix(logStreamNamePrefix)
                .startTime(startTime)
                .endTime(endTime)
                .build();

        int logLimit = this.cloudWatchLogsClient.filterLogEvents(filterLogEventsRequest).events().size();

        for (int c = 0; c < logLimit; c++) {
            logMessages.add(
                    this.cloudWatchLogsClient.filterLogEvents(filterLogEventsRequest).events().get(c).message());
        }

        return logMessages;

    } catch (CloudWatchException e) {
        log.error(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
    }

    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Comment: Cloudwatch logs is slow to query. And you query twice, once to get the number of logs and then to iterate over them, certainly not a good idea.